# Whats the difference between Q Promise library's .finally() and .done()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

What is the difference between using the Nodejs Q promise library's .finally() and .done() statements.

For example whats the difference between these two?

```
Q(...)
.then(...)
.finally(); //or fin()

Q(..)
.then()
.done();
```

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `.then`, `.finally` and `.done`?

Comment: I have read the docs, and did not find the answer to be so obvious myself.

Comment: promise is now part of the JS spec, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`promise.done(onSuccess, onError)` simply allows you to process resolved value. An additional benefit is that does not imply any error swallowing (as it is the case with `promise.then()`), it guarantees that any involved  exception would be exposed. It also effectively ends the chain and does not return any further promise.

`promise.finally(fn)` is for registering a task that must be done after a given promise resolves (it doesn't matter whether promise succeeds or fails). Usually, you use it for some kind of cleanup operations e.g. imagine you set up a progress bar, that needs to be hidden after the request is done (no matter if it was successful), then just do `promise.finally(hideProgressBar)`. Additionally `promise.finally()` returns input promise, so you can return it for further processing.

Comment: And what the difference between .catch and .fail method ?

Comment: `.catch(cb)` is an alias for `.then(null, cb)`. While `.fail` never really settled in Promise A+ libraries. I think Q had it before `catch` was coined, and it done exactly what `catch` does now. In jQuery `fail` takes just fail callbacks `done` style (with no error swallowing implied). In my implementation I consider to add `.fail(cb)` as an alias for `.done(null, cb)` -> https://github.com/medikoo/deferred/issues/35

Comment: I like the analogy on [ www.promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org#then) section on Transformation/Chaining : "Put simply, `.then` is to `.done` as `.map` is to `.forEach`. To put that another way, use `.then` whenever you're going to do something with the result (even if that's just waiting for it to finish) and use `.done` whenever you aren't planning on doing anything with the result."

Answer (score 9):

The difference is in chaining and error handling, and error logging:

```
Q(...)
.then(...) 
.finally();
```

Here, if the `then` throws, the `finally` will still run, but no error will log. In Q `finally` is run regardless of the `.then` being successful or not. This is like the `finally` keyword in JS `try/catch/finally`. It is also possible to chain additional `then`s to the chain in this case.

```
Q(..)
.then()
.done();
```

Here, `done` indicates that the promise chain has ended, you can not chain to it any more. If you pass it only an onFulfilled handler it will not run if the `then` threw, and it will log errors if it ends with an exception.